# SQL Server - Sorting by datepart week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. When I try to sort information by week using the datepart function it returns no values. There are values in my table for the selected date range.

The query I am trying to use is:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
set @StartDate = '20120401 00:00:00'
set @EndDate = '20120430 23:59:59'
;WITH
mytablePlusHours As
(
SELECT *,
    DATEPART(ww, [eci_date])     AS [dateWeek]
FROM    [mytable]    
)
, mytableHourGroups As
(
SELECT  dateWeek, 
        [eci_country],
        COUNT(*)        As [Number_Country],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dateWeek ORDER BY [eci_country])
                        As [Country_Rank]
FROM        mytablePlusHours
GROUP BY    dateWeek, [eci_country]
)
SELECT  
    dateWeek     AS [eci_date],
    [eci_country],
    [Number_Country]
FROM    mytableHourGroups WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE   [dateWeek] between @StartDate and @EndDate
ORDER BY [dateWeek], [Number_Country] DESC
```

I can pull information by day but I cannot figure out how to sort it by week. Can someone please advise me where my code is wrong? Thanks!

I am trying to display my data like:

```
Week Country       Count
16   United States  13
17   Canada         41
```

Comment: So are you saying it is not honoring `ORDER BY [dateWeek]`? Did you mean to also sort by country?

Comment: @AaronBertrand he is comparing the int week to date values, which is causing all rows to be filtered out.

Comment: Ah, so there are NO rows. I thought there were rows that weren't sorted correctly.

Comment: Yeah I think so based on `it returns no values.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[DateWeek]` isn't a date, it's a number (1 to 53).

Either...

Move the `WHERE` clause to your first CTE.

```
mytablePlusHours As
(
  SELECT *, DATEPART(ww, [eci_date])     AS [dateWeek]
    FROM [mytable]
   WHERE [eci_date] between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
```

Or, change the `DATEPART()` to a function that returns a date...

```
mytablePlusHours As
(
  SELECT *, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [eci_date]), 0) AS [dateWeek]
    FROM [mytable]
)
```

Comment: How would i start the week on saturday and not monday?

Comment: @Brad - I'm at home and on an iPhone, so I can't test it, but something like this should work `DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, [eci_date]+2), -2)`  *[The `+2` offsets the date, so that Sat-Fri all give the same result in the DATEDIFF(), and the `-2` offsets the result back to a Saturday.  Hopefully.]*

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing an integer to a date.

`DATEPART(ww...)` returns the numerical week (i.e. 3 for the third week of the year).  Your comparisons are `datetime` which is not directly comparable.

You need to compare to the week of the dates, and you should also check the year.  To check just the week:

```
WHERE   [dateWeek] between  DATEPART(ww,@StartDate) and DATEPART(ww,@EndDate)
```

You should add year to your CTE and compare that as well, otherwise 1/15/2012 and 1/9/2011 will both show up in the same "week".